# Chrome Extension permissions removed when user signs out of account?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a Chrome Extension and have used the chrome.identity authorisation flow to grant permissions for the extension: (manifest V3)

**manifest.json**

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "###",
    "scopes": [
      "openid", 
      "email", 
      "https://mail.google.com/",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic"
    ]
  },
```

I have the authorisation window popping up and after clicking 'allow' I can see that valid tokens are granted and the permissions appear in the privacy section for the extension.

However, if the user signs out of their account, then the granted permissions disappear. I have another chrome extension installed that requests the same/similar permissions and the permissions granted on that extension persist even after sign out.

How do I make the permissions persist after sign out? Can this be done with chrome.identity?

Any help appreciated,

Basil

Comment: The behavior you're observing, where the granted permissions disappear after the user signs out of their account, is expected and is a result of how Chrome's identity API and authorization flow work.

Comment: So I would need to use an alternative authorization flow? any recommendations on the correct oauth2 to use?